# Power sensor 230 V

Tags: sensor, gpio

I would like to use a Raspberry PI to log when a heat pump is turning on and off.

The pump is running on 230 V; what I need is a circuit that can detect changes in voltage level and translate that to something low-voltage that the RPI's GPIO pins understand.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

As you are asking this queston, I assume that you knowledge of electronics is very limited. Hence my advice is optimized for safety, not for easy building or cost.

You could wire an ordinary wall-wart in parallel to the pump. Use two resistors at the output of the wall-wart (or a resistor and a LED) to create a Pui-compatible signal. For instance, for a 12V DC wall-wart, use a 1 kOhm resistor and a LED, and have the Pi sense the LED voltage. Note that it will take some time for the voltage to fall after the pump is switched off.

Another approach would be to get a reed-switch and wind one of the wires to the pump some number of times around the reed switch. Expect 20-50 turns. You can connect the reed switch as you would connect any other switch.

If you can get a relay with a 230V coil you could put that coil parallel to the pump and read one of the switch contacts.

Yet another option would be to wire a lamp in parallel to the pump, have the lamp illumibate an LDR, and read out the LDR.

Comment: Or you could attach a microphone to the pump and monitor the output.